# C++: Issues with boost::filesystem on server (locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid)

Tags: c++, boost, ubuntu-12.04

i have a problem running my C++ project on our faculty server. The runtime error i get is this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I determined that the problem lies somewhere within this filesystem iterator (by utilizing a test program):

```
bf::path dir("ImageData/" + m_object_type);

vector<bf::path> tmp;
copy(bf::directory_iterator(dir), bf::directory_iterator(), back_inserter(tmp));
sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
for (vector<bf::path>::const_iterator it(tmp.begin()); it != tmp.end(); ++it)
{
    auto name = *it;
    image_names.push_back(name.string());
}
```

The program ran perfectly on two other Linux-based system (kubuntu & linux mint, but as my project is quite runtime heavy and running it with different parameters would take about 28 days on my machine i really want to use the server). I already tried various paths but none of it worked. I read about a boost bug which led to this error before 1.47, but i'm using 1.54 on the server. I also checked the system locales but that doesn't really gave me a clue since they are almost similar to my system. The other specification of the server are:

Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-29-generic x86_64)
g/c++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

If anyone has any idea to share, i would appreciate it.

Comment: Not really an answer, but you could just remove usage of boost::filesystem, and scan the directory directly (e.g. using opendir/readdir)

Answer (score 3):

This is an [issue with Boost < 1.56](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4688).  Boost internally tries to construct a `std::locale("")` (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/src/path.cpp, and compare the updated version in [v1.56](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/filesystem/src/path.cpp)).  This call will fail if the locale (or `LC_ALL`) is invalid.

In my case, it was a call to `boost::filesystem::create_directories()` that triggered the `locale("")` call.

The following workaround worked for me: Override the `LC_ALL` environment variable in your program.  `std::locale("")` seems to use that variable to determine what the “sensible default” locale should be.

```
#include <locale>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **)
{
  try {
    std::locale loc("");
    std::cout << "Setting locale succeeded." << std::endl;
  } catch (const std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << "Setting locale failed: " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  // Set LC_ALL=C, the "classic" locale
  setenv("LC_ALL", "C", 1);
  // Second attempt now works for me:
  try {
    std::locale loc("");
    std::cout << "Setting locale succeeded." << std::endl;
  } catch (const std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << "Setting locale failed: " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

After the `setenv` call, I can create a default `locale`, and the `boost::filesystem` calls work as well.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know for sure, but I suspect that this program will behave the same:

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

int main () {
    try { std::locale foo (""); }
    catch ( std::runtime_error & ex ) { std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl; }  
    }
```

Also, this (old) ticket https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5289 may shed some light on the subject.

EDIT: Technically, this is not an answer.

Comment: I found the other tickets but not this one, i'll look into it and try the patch, even if it's pretty antique. Thanks

Comment: in general, I think that the problem is on your production machine that the default locale `""` doesn't exist or is not valid.

Comment: I don't understand how this could result in the runtime error. The directories i'm working on have a one word name like "apple" and the images inside are all labeled like this "apple-023". (I'm also not sure how to use that patch since path.cpp is much more complex in the 1.54 build compared to 1.46).

Answer (score -1):

for anyone who is interested, here is a version of the above directory iterator utilizing the QT-lib:

```
string str1 = "ImageData/";
QString dir_string1 = QString::fromStdString(str1);
QString dir_string2 = QString::fromStdString(m_object_type);

dir_string1.append(dir_string2);
QDir dir(dir_string1);

dir.setFilter(QDir::Files);
dir.setSorting(QDir::Name); 

QStringList entries = dir.entryList();

string tmp;

for (QStringList::ConstIterator it=entries.begin(); it != entries.end(); ++it)
{
    auto name = *it;
    tmp = name.toUtf8().constData();
    image_names.push_back(str1 + m_object_type + "/" + tmp);
}
```